# How to configure automated email alert in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server-2012

I need to identify and be notified when records in my SQL Server 2012 database table meet a specific condition. For example, when a record in the trans_record table has any entries in the “status” column of “error”.

The query is simple enough and I have setup an SSIS package to query the table with the appropriate “where” clause. I followed this with a SQL Agent job to run the SSIS package daily at 7:00am and export the offending records to a flat text file.

What I need to understand is how I can be emailed only when a record is found with the query performed by the SSIS package. It appears that the SSIS package will always create a file regardless if any records are found.

I see that SQL Server supports Alerts and defined Operators to be notified, but I don’t understand how to be notified only if my query returns a valid record.

How can I set this up in SQL Server?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you would like to be emailed by SSIS only when there is a record in the table with a status of error. If this is correct then you can achieve this from SSIS package.

If you would like to query the database and send an email, then you will require two Tasks and two connections:

1. Execute SQL task
2. Send Email Task
3. Database Connection
4. Email connection

Configure connections with relevant database connection details and exchange details for email connection.

Add the connections to the tasks, create Precedence Constraint from the Exec SQL to Send Email task.

In the Exec SQL create query or use stored procedure to return false or true if the record exists, or if you prefer count of the records in the table.

Return the outcome of the query to the variable (SSIS variable, you will have to add it in the package). Change the settings on the Precedence Constraint to add evaluation of expression and use your variable i.e. if you set the variable to be @recordPresent then the evaluation will be @recordPresent==true (if the value returned is false or true) or @recordPresent > 0 (if the variables contains the count of records).

If the expression evaluates to true and constraint is of the type requiered i.e. success, completion, failed the control will be passed to the next task in this case Email.  If Send an email task is set correctly (from, to, subject and Body of the email as well as exchange connection string is correct), email will only be sent when there is a record in the table.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Not to worry, glad I was able to help.